# C# Listview - How to change the color of each new item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I add items to a `ListView` control from the click event of a `Button`. I want each **new** item to be colored **red** and the **older** items colored **white** (so only the newest item added to the `ListView` is colored red).

I did something like this, but it only alternates the colors between red and white:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= listView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].Index % 2 == 0)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

How can I have only the newest added item to be colored red?

Comment: How does that code tell new items from older ones?  Its just alternating.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, that is my question. I want to color the newest added item. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: @mageos I am using Windows Forms.

Comment: No, thats ***my*** question.  That little snippet gives us no clue how one item can be determined to be older or new.  The answer to the TITLE is to set the color when you add new items

Comment: Why don't you show the code where you add an item? Isn't that the place where you want to set the color?

Comment: `I want to color the newest added item` is *that* going to be the last one only?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, I want to color the last item only. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of items are you adding to the listview?

Comment: @MG91, in the future you might want to take the time to research what your next problem and or issue may be, read how to ask a question on here, and please learn how to execute a basic google search and show some greater degree of effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new method to add items to your listView:

```
public void AddNewItemToListBox(string text)
{
  // Make existing background white      
  for (int i = 0; i <= listView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White;
  }
  // New one with red background
  ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(); 
  lvi.Text = text;
  lvi.BackColor = Color.Red;
  lv.Items.Add(lvi); // lv is your listview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void listView_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ItemIndex != (listView.Items.Count - 1))
        {
            // Draw the background and focus rectangle for a selected item.
        }
        else
        {
            // Draw the background for an unselected item.
            using (LinearGradientBrush brush =new LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.Red, Color.Red, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            }
        }

        // Draw the item text for views other than the Details view.
        if (listView.View != View.Details)
        {
            e.DrawText();
        }
    }
```